# Cannot read property (Angular6 + Firebase)

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm learning Angular and Firebase and building a test project. I'm stuck with receiving data from Firebase.

There is the project - https://embed.plnkr.co/lpwsbuVpS3MuAYpnTgRY/
* (but unfortunatelu it's not running)

The main idea - we have list of servers on main page of the app. By clicking on Edit button we could go to `/server-info/{server-id}` page and see all details of current server.

So the problem, I'm faced with, is when you go to edit page, there is an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'mainip' of undefined`. Here is the code of ServerInfoComponent

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from "firebase";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-info',
  templateUrl: './server-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-info.component.css']
})
export class ServerInfoComponent implements OnInit {

  id: string;
  currentServer: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  getServerInfo() {
    firebase.database().ref('Servers/' + this.id).on('value', snap => {
      this.currentServer = snap.val();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // get id of current server
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.getServerInfo();
  }

}
```

`console.log()` into `getServerInfo()` method return an object with needful data

Actualy, it was working until I decided to create db.service.ts where I planned to add all methods to work with Firebase. I changed AllServersComponent to work with this service and after that ServerInfo page break.

Comment: Here is a link to working project - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdyzbr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your component gets created `currentServer` is undefined. You make a call to get a value for it, but it isn't there immediately and Angular renders the page in that state. In your html `{{ currentServer.mainip }}` is what is causing the issue. That is why you are seeing `TypeError: Cannot read property 'mainip' of undefined`, `currentServer` is undefined.

There are a number of ways to solve this depending on what you would like to have happen. The easiest would be to use Angular's `null/undefined` checking syntax. Change your html to: `{{ currentServer?.mainip }}`. As the view gets rendered the first time, `currentServer` will be `undefined` and so Angular will return an empty string. When your call to Firebase returns and assigns a value to `currentServer`(assuming that the data call returns with an object and not a `null` or `undefined` value), the view will update and read the `mainip` property value from your object and render that to the screen.

UPDATE

If you don't want to show the screen to the user until the data has been received from firebase, there are at least two options...

1. The simplest is to use *ngIf
2. The correct way is to use the resolve in your router as documented on [angular's site](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data)

UPDATE 2

Change your `ngOnit` to the following(`ParamMap` is imported from '@angular/router'):

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.id = params.get('id');
      this.getServerInfo();
    });
  }
```

Comment: I see your point. But I'd like to display mainip of current server. Is it possible show data when component receive data? When I added {{ currentServer?.mainip }} nothing changed, just no error in console, but data not displayed too

Comment: You're plunkr doesn't work for me at all, so it is very difficult to help with this issue. If it isn't showing anything, it would seem to indicate that your call isn't being made or is returning the data in a shape that you aren't expecting.

Comment: Stackblitz might be a better place to put a working example

Comment: Unfortunately, I've uploaded my project there and cannot share it, even after saving. It's Sending redirect to new project through shared link (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzdwjv)

Comment: I've added it to projects (on localhost and on Stackblitz), but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is going on because I do not see where you use the class Server. But I would change you class

```
export class Server {
    constructor(
        public mainip: string,
        public provider: string,
        public company: string
    ) {}
}
```

into a interface

```
export interface Server {
        mainip: string;
        provider: string;
        company: string;
}
```

Seems that you are creating the class and assigning it to an undefined.